# Sails.JS - retry on NTLM Auth failure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, ntlm

I am currently writing a NodeJS application based on Sails.JS, and I'm using ntlm-express for NTLM authentication. This works perfectly fine when the authentication succeeds but in cases where it fails (for example, a Firefox user entering wrong credentials) ntlm-express returns a 500 error code, FireFox stores the credentials in its cache and the user is unable to login to the web app at all, since he's not getting a new prompt to enter credentials. The only way for the user to log in is to manually clear the authentication cache in FireFox and try again.

What I'd like to do is in cases where ntlm-express fails to authenticate the user, to prompt him again for credentials instead of returning 500.

Has anyone done something like this and can point me in the right direction? I found very little information online regarding this topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who runs into a similar issue, I managed to solve it by overriding the express-ntlm forbidden function to return a 401 instead of of 500 and editing the default Sails unauthorized.js response to also return a "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM" header.
That way I am forcing the client to retry NTLM negotiation until he gets it right...